# PHP: $_SESSION[] click twice

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have to create a wordpress website, which I've almost finished. Now I got some problems with the menu. I have to check which menu item is clicked (without page_id=""). So I found `$_SESSION`. I created 2 templates:

Template 1: Products - This is what I've got in the products.php site:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Products
*/

get_header();

$_SESSION['showActive'] = "product"; 

if (have_posts()) :while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="contentslideshow">
    <?php the_uds_billboard("billboard") ?>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have to say that there is a redirect of another page. And in this page I choose "Template: Products" in WP backend.

And then I got the other template: Home:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/

get_header();

$_SESSION['showActive'] = "home"; 

if (have_posts()) :while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="contentslideshow">
    <?php the_uds_billboard("billboard") ?>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

There is another redirect and I did the same like before. I choose "Template: Home" in WP backend. Now I check in `header.php` in menu div:

```
<div id="lower">
            <a href="#" class="tab1<?php if($_SESSION['showActive'] == 'home'){ echo " tab-active"; } else{ echo ""; }  ?>">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="tab3<?php if($_SESSION['showActive'] == 'product'){ echo " tab-active"; } else{ echo ""; }  ?>">Products</a>
        </div>
```

So if the `$_SESSION` is "product" it should add the class `tab-active` to "Products" menu item. And if the `$_SESSION` is "home" it should add the class `tab-active` to "Home" menu item.

But I have to click twice on the menu item that the class is correctly added.
Can someone give me a hint?

Cheers

Comment: why are not using default wordpress menu ? They will keep current active menu details.

Comment: It's a selfmade template and the situation of this is a bit complicated to explain here and it won't have a relation to the code :)

Comment: Since you are using sessions, you need `session_start();` inside all your pages as the first line under your opening `<?php` tags, seeing that it's not posted in your code.

Comment: Assign session value in the header not on the template.I think you are assigning the value after the page loads.Try to assign $_SESSION['showActive'] = "home";  on header.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Mh, you mean in the templates code or in header?

Comment: @Roman As I wrote, first line under your opening PHP tags, in all your files using the same session. I.e.: `<?php session_start(); // rest of your code ?>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Either I did it completely wrong cause I missunderstood you or it doesn't work. I added in all .php files I got on the first line `<?php session_start(); ?>` This should be right or have I completely missunderstood you?

Comment: @Roman `<?php /* Template Name: Products */ session_start(); get_header(); // rest of your code........`

Comment: @Fred-ii- i think the problem is not session starting here.His code works but on second click.He is assigning the session value below menu code that's why  he loads page twice.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah thats what I have but it doesn't work

Comment: @MahmoodRehman Ok, well any which way, `session_start();` needs to be present. As far as the actual problem goes, I don't know where it is.

Comment: @Roman Did you try code on my way ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman the problem is, if I assign `$_SESSION['showActive'] = "home"` on `header.php`, it doesn't know on which page it should load it. If I assign it in `template-products.php` it knows that it just have to be active if the page "Products" is loaded. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Ah nice one. I understand what you meant with "below menu code". I had to put `$_SESSION['showActive'] = "product"` on top next to `<?php` starting tag. It works fine now :) Thank you guys!

Comment: Thats great if your problem solved.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman I can't accept an answer but I'd like to because you helped me a lot with your hint. Maybe you can write this comment as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using session on page you must declare `session_start()` in the beginning of the page.Since your problem is that menu get selected on second time page loads its mean you are assigning value to session wrong time.Try to assign value at the header portion like i suggest you in comments portion or on the page top before the menu loads.
check the page id or slug then set the session value like

```
if(pageid=='1' or slug =='home')
{ $session_value = 'home';}elseif(...)
```

Hopes it will help you.